# Pushing a map off a disk

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let us assume that we have covered $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the open sets $V = 2 \cdot int(D^n)$ (the standard unit disk, and 2 means multiply the size by 2) and the family $\mathcal{U}$ of open disks W such that $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n - D^n$ . Say that we have a function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and that we have chosen a m so fine that for every integer $0 \leq k \leq m$, $f([k/m,(k+1)/m])$ is completely contained in V or an open set of $\mathcal{U}$. Let $L$ be the union of all intervals mapping into $V$. Let us now consider the function $u : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow I$ such that $u(x)=1$ if $|x| \geq 2/3$, and  $u(x)=0$ if $|x| \leq 1/3$. Define $v(x)=1-u(x)$. One can then find a piecewise-linear function $g_L(x): L \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g_L(k/m) = f(k/m)$. Now, define $g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by $g(x) = u(f(x))f(x)+v(f(x))g_L(x)$ (this is well-defined and continuous, which can be checked on each interval $[k/m,(k+1)/m]$. Now, I want to show that $int(D^n)$ is NOT contained in $g(I)$. I suppose this has something to do with inequalities, but I can't make this to work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Right, thank you! I will edit.

Comment: how do you define $g(x)$ when $x \notin L$ ? Also, if your goal is to show that there is one point in the disk not reached by $g$, it's hardly the goal described in the title (pushing the map off the disk)

Comment: @mercio When $x \notin L$, the $g_L$-term gets cancelled out by v!

Comment: Then what's the point of introducing $L$ ?

Comment: @mercio: The point is that on L, we have a piecewise-linear function that is homotopic to f , which is important for another part of the problem in question.

Comment: This result is false is you start with some space-filling curve.